# Error in connection string, PHP with MySQL deployed in Azure

Tags: php, mysql, azure, connection-string

I am working in a project which consist on deploying PHP web site in Azure and connecting with an Azure MySQL.

I started by creating and migrating the data in Azure MySQL. I also created the PHP web site and deployed the code but when added the connection string on configuration part of the web app it gives me an error:

> value is a required property on all connection strings

the connection string:

```
$con=mysqli_init(); [mysqli_ssl_set($con, NULL, NULL, {ca-cert filename}, NULL, NULL);] mysqli_real_connect($con, {your_host}, {username@servername}, {your_password}, {your_database}, {your_port});
```

I cannot save the connection string because the error is in red below the tab of the connection string.

Because I don't have experience with PHP and MySQL I googled the error but haven't found anything.

Comment: You do not pass key and certificate path

Comment: Can you explain please.

Comment: You pass lots off `NULL` as parameter, I don't think it will work

Comment: I copied this connection string from the MySQL db. I added the server, dbname, userId and the password. How can be a connection string without the `null` in PHP?

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl?

Comment: I can connect normally with workbench. The problem is when I want to connect php web site with this MySQL db. I enter the connection string with server, userId, password and port and gives me in red the error I have enter in the post.

Comment: Have you configured SSL for your Azure mysql database?

Comment: No haven't ssl configured. The problem is not the ssl but I can't save my connection string in php web app.

Comment: Is that you want to manually add the connection string in your Azure web app?

Comment: Yes I want to add the connection string as can be done for asp .net web app

Comment: @Llazar, did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: @JoePlatano yes I solved incorporated the connection in a file not in azure and fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add my sql connection string in Azure web app, please refer to the following step

1. Get connection string
   [image]
2. Add connection string in Azure web app
   [image]
3. Enable access from an Azure App Service to an Azure Database for MySQL

   Azure Database for MySQL provides access security using a firewall to protect your data. When connecting from an Azure App Service to Azure Database for MySQL server, keep in mind that the outbound IPs of App Service are dynamic in nature. Choosing the "**Allow access to Azure services**" option will allow the app service to connect to the MySQL server.
   [image]
4. upload perm file via kudu
   [image]
5. Connect Azure MySQL with php

```
<?php
$connectstr_dbhost = '';
$connectstr_dbname = '';
$connectstr_dbusername = '';
$connectstr_dbpassword = '';
foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, "MYSQLCONNSTR_") !== 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $connectstr_dbhost = preg_replace("/^.*Data Source=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbname = preg_replace("/^.*Database=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbusername = preg_replace("/^.*User Id=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbpassword = preg_replace("/^.*Password=(.+?)$/", "\\1", $value);
}

$conn = mysqli_init();
mysqli_ssl_set($conn,NULL,NULL, "D:/home/site/wwwroot/Cert/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem", NULL, NULL) ;
mysqli_real_connect($conn, $connectstr_dbhost, $connectstr_dbusername, $connectstr_dbpassword, $connectstr_dbname, 3306, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
die('Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The  database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($conn) . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

[image]

Comment: I have used this connection string ```$con=mysqli_init(); [mysqli_ssl_set($con, NULL, NULL, {ca-cert filename}, NULL, NULL);] mysqli_real_connect($con, {your_host}, {username@servername}, {your_password}, {your_database}, {your_port});``` . You have used the other, can you explain please the difference.

Comment: have you configured SSL for Azure mysql(https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/Azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl)? If you do not configure it, you can use my code.

Comment: The app is ready works in development just I need to connect the db. I want just the connection. If you have experience with php & MySQL please write the connection string that works for you.